# Compile Error: App\Kernel::registerBundles(): Failed opening required while deploying website

Tags: symfony4

I'm working on `NetBeans` in a project built on `Symfony4`.
The project runs ok on mode **dev** aswell as on mode **prod**, buy when I deploy it son the web:

> "Compile Error: App\Kernel::registerBundles(): Failed opening
>   required...".

If I change the server php version to 7, the result in Error500 (to generic to know where the problem is).
On server `php` 7.1 the error is App\Kernel... 
Some info about the project :

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.7",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^4.1",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^1.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/templating": "^4.0",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "requirements-checker": "script",
            "security-checker security:check": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"

...}
```

Any idea how to solve this problem ?
Should I rewrite the site ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think your deployment is in cause. Please explain how you process. Be specific.

Comment: To deploy the files I use FTP.

Comment: I suppose the problem commes from different bundles versions.

Comment: Did you forget vendors? Do you use rsync to be sure everything is in place?

Comment: I'm updating compser and it sends an error : InvalidArgumentException. Pakcage is not installed: friendsofsymfony/user-bundle-9999999-dev. If I apply a require following the request, it doesn't work as 9999999-dev doesn't exist (?). If I require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle, same error [InvalidArgumentException]. Then, if I update composer it never stops!!! The process cache:clear exeeded (?).

Comment: Are vendors updated while in prod mode cache:clear and warm-up chache ? That works in local. Errors are cleaned after this 2 chache:clear

Comment: Is any conflict between Sonata, friendsofsymfony and/or sensio ? I fact I require sonata, but it is not in use at this moment.

Comment: If the composer install is ok on your side, then it's related to the remote configuration. You run `composer install` from the cli? If so, then you should check composer version and PHP version. `composer --version` & `php --version`.

Comment: Sorry Nek. I'm not sure about the rsync process. In FTP there are all files generated by Symfony, and at public file, my site docs, .htacces, check.php and index.php. docs.  The only file I modified was the index.php: I "commented" the [APP_ENV]. Do I need to write a php command? to execute rsync ??

Comment: Please answer to questions about version. Do you have an SSH access to the machine you're working on?

Comment: I've made this process yesterday... but nothing. So I've uninstall and then unstall composer. ok, but same error.

Comment: So comcoser version is the latest one: 1.6.4 and my internal server is 7.2.1

Comment: No, I don't have SSH access to my external server. I know I can just change version server from 7 to 7.2. Version 7= white page or error500; 7.1 &7.2= Compile Error: App\Kernel::registerBundles(): Failed opening required '/home/config/Bundles.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php7.1/lib/php') in Kernel.php (line 29)

Comment: So your error has nothing to do with deployment but occur on your computer before the deployment? If you try `composer install`, I guess you obtain an error? You give many errors. You need to be more specific on how you obtain these errors. As I understand at the moment, you have 2 issues: 1 on the server the error `Failed opening required '/home/config/Bundles.php' ` (which is probably a rights error) and `InvalidArgumentException. Pakcage is not installed: friendsofsymfony/user-bundle-9999999-dev` which occurs when you try use `composer install`. Please confirm.

Comment: @Nek, I'm a beginner in web development, if it is very important to have a SSH to install a Symfony project, I'll change my host options... I'd really want to see my website on line! I read I could install vendors from console, is that correct ?

Comment: It is better to have a command line to install a Symfony project, so you can execute Symfony commands like clear cache (otherwise you need to drop the cache folder). Generate assets (webpack or assetic). and do many command line tasks... Yes the access to command line is highly recommended. Then you can take a look at deployer.org which is a tool to help you deploy with SSH.

Comment: If I try composer install into my project folder, the info is as follows: Nothing to install or update, Generating autoload files   ocramius/package versions: generating version class... ocramius/package-versions:...done generating version class.   Executing script chache:clear...         Symfony\omponent\Porcess\Exception\ProcessTimeOutException     The process ""C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "--php.ini=C \xampp\php\php.ini" "bin/console" cache:clear" exeeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

Comment: @Nek The problem ...could be solved by SSH mode ?                         As you can see, the problem commes from a bundle...user ? how could I know where it comme from?

Comment: @Nek. Concerning installation of friendsofsymfony/user-bundle-9999999-dev...the answer is: InvalidArgymentEception. Could not find a matching version of package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle-9999999-dev. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and the package is available in a stability which matches your minumum-stability (stable). Any idea to how resolve this problem ?

Comment: I think stackoverflow is not the best place to solve your problem because there is too much questions you need answers. Can you consider to use another channel like Symfony Slack Dev (https://symfony.com/slack-invite) on channel #support or IRC #symfony@irc.freenode.net ?

Comment: Ok. I'll go. Thaks!

Answer (score 3):

Hi @moni i have this error: [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIUEu.png)

And my solution later than i search and search for days is this:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/kernel.html#project-directory

> If for some reason the composer.json file is not stored at the root of
>   your project, you can override the getProjectDir() method to return
>   the right project directory:

and you have to override getProjectDir function on your

> src/Kernel.php

file like this:

```
public function getProjectDir()
{
    return realpath(__DIR__.'/../');
}
```

And thats all my symfony now find my bundle.php file and now works like a charm ! hope it works for you !

Answer (score 0):

I got also the same problem. I think the problem was du the fact that the symfony project on the local machine was not in main partition where u have the admin right. And I noticed that on the server the cache file is not created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).